# GRPC Service Discovery

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Given the address of a [GRPC](http://www.grpc.io/) service at, say, `ipv4:127.0.0.1:25000`, are there any standardized queries or tools I can use to discover what GRPC requests the service is capable of receiving?

e.g. I'm looking for something like:

```
./magic-grpc-service-tool 127.0.0.1:25000
> service Greeter {
>    rpc Greet(HelloMessage) returns (HelloResponse) {}
> }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: the reflection service is supported across the various languages and grpc CLI is able to consume it.

At the moment, no. We will be adding [server reflection](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md) to the various languages, but the support has to be added to each individually. Once server reflection is supported, the [grpc CLI](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/util/grpc_cli.cc) will be enhanced to use it and will be the "standard tool" to use.

Comment: this feature is available currently or not

Comment: It varies per-language. I think it is implemented in C++, and is in the works for Java. I think the CLI supports reflection at this point, but there may still be additional features to be added.